# Split image in parts

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to reproduce something like this image (taken from NBA.com )[image]

What I have :
- A court with the white lines
- A list of Position for each shot and I know if they are made or missed.

But I'm stuck on the method to realize the image :
Should I create images for each part of the field using photoshop/paint.net and then color it in c# ? 
Of course the best way would be to have an equation for each part so I can check easily if the position is in and I could also draw it.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decide on how replicable you need the solution. If you need it for a 1-10 pictures, then don't bother with code- it will most surely take much longer to fine tune it.

If was to work on this specific image, I would probably take my time to find expressions for all lines to make calculations more precise though.

Comment: I need to draw just this image !